# Why can't an F# type provider generated type be used as a function parameter?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to setup an F# function that takes a parameter of a type generated by the FSharp.Data type provider for JSON. Here is one attempt using a simple sample from the docs.

```ml
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data,5.0.2"

open FSharp.Data

type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
let simple = Simple.Parse(""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """)

let print (s:Simple) =
    printfn $"{s.Age}"
    printfn $"{s.Name}"
    
print simple
```

This won't compile and within my `print` function `s` does not have an `Age` or `Name` property.

However, if I use the simple instance right after it is created without trying to pass it into a function, it works fine.

```ml
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data,5.0.2"

open FSharp.Data

type Simple = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>
let simple = Simple.Parse(""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """)

printfn $"{simple.Age}"
printfn $"{simple.Name}"
```

Are instances of type provider generated types limited to being used within the same scope where they are created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of the JSON type provider, `Simple` is a type that does not actually represent any data from the JSON file. It is basically just a placeholder for all the different types that the type provider needs to generate for the individual records in the JSON.

The top-level record is named `Root` and is a nested type of `Simple`, so the following works:

```
let print (s:Simple.Root) =
    printfn $"{s.Age}"
    printfn $"{s.Name}"
```

The names of these types are "guessed" by the type provider, typically based on the names of the records that contain them. In a more complex example, there would be two different types (`Sample.A` and `Sample.Root`) and you can use both as arguments (you just need to figure out which one is which, from the IDE tooltips):

```
type Simple = JsonProvider<"""{ "a": { "name":"John", "age":94 } }""">
let simple = Simple.Parse(""" { "a": { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } }""")

let print (s:Simple.A) =
    printfn $"{s.Age}"
    printfn $"{s.Name}"
    
print simple.A
```